# $\sup_{j\leq min(m,n)}\vert\sigma_j(A)-\sigma_j(B)\vert\leq\Vert A-B\Vert_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove the following inequality:

$\sup_{j\leq min(m,n)}\vert\sigma_j(A)-\sigma_j(B)\vert\leq\Vert A-B\Vert_F$, where $\sigma$ is the singular values and $\Vert *\Vert_F$ is the frobenius norm.

I have been hinted to use the weyl's inequaltiy. The following is my try so far. Thanks for any help in advance.

---

Given j.$\sup_{j\leq min(m,n)}\vert\sigma_j(A)-\sigma_j(B)\vert=\sqrt{\lambda_j(A^TA)}-\sqrt{\lambda_j(B^TB)}\\
\leq\sqrt{\lambda_j(A^TA)-\lambda_j(B^TB)}\\
\leq\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA-B^TB)}\\
=\sqrt{\sigma_{max}(A^TA-B^TB)}\\
=\sqrt{\max_{\Vert x\Vert\leq1}{x^TA^TAx-x^TB^TBx}}\\
=\sqrt{\max_{\Vert x\Vert\leq1}tr({x^TA^TAx-x^TB^TBx}})\\
=\sqrt{\Vert A\Vert_F^2+\Vert B\Vert_F^2}$

where the second line is from $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$, the fourth line follows from the matrix inside is symmetric, the fifth line follows from the definintion of spectral norm, and the final line follows from some algebras of trace operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the variational characterisation of singular values, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_j(A)
&=\max_{\dim V=j}\min_{\substack{x\in V\\ \|x\|_2=1}}\|Ax\|_2\\
&=\max_{\dim V=j}\min_{\substack{x\in V\\ \|x\|_2=1}}\|(A-B)x+Bx\|_2\\
&\le\max_{\dim V=j}\min_{\substack{x\in V\\ \|x\|_2=1}}\left(\|(A-B)x\|_2+\|Bx\|_2\right)\\
&\le\max_{\dim V=j}\min_{\substack{x\in V\\ \|x\|_2=1}}\left(\|A-B\|_2+\|Bx\|_2\right)\\
&=\max_{\dim V=j}\min_{\substack{x\in V\\ \|x\|_2=1}}\|Bx\|_2+\|A-B\|_2\\
&=\sigma_j(B)+\|A-B\|_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly, by interchanging the roles of $A$ and $B$, we also obtain $\sigma_j(B)\le\sigma_j(A)+\|A-B\|_2$. Hence $|\sigma_j(A)-\sigma_j(B)|\le\|A-B\|_2\le\|A-B\|_F$.